# Linear Algebra Minimization of Norm

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $A^+$ be the psuedo inverse of $A$, $I$ be the identity matrix, $z\in\{0,1\}^{n\times 1}$, and $h\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$ where $z$ is unknown. Define,

$w = (I - AA^+)z$

We wish to minimize the following quantity wth respect to $z$.

$\|(AA^+ +\displaystyle\frac{1}{\|w\|}ww^T)h - h\|$

where $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm. Besides this general case, are there specific cases in which a general method of minimization might be applicable?

Comment: Which variable do you vary?

Comment: Hi, sorry. Made a large edit to the initial post.